# solr - troubleshooting synonym filter and cache

Tags: solr

All of my old synonyms are working in the Analyzer.

I recently added teddy => roosevelt just to test it out and it doesn't parse. I'm wondering if it's a cache issue, although I made the change a week ago.

Even more problematic is that even though I see my old synonyms are being parsed on the Analyzer, they are not being parsed in my actual application (WordPress).

If I have A, B:
A: 10 hits
B: 26 hits

So far my troubleshooting checklist has been:

- Analyzer and application are pointing to installed instance (data/solr/conf/synonyms.txt)
- Delete a working synonym in synonyms.txt and Analyze: **This actually fails to pass.** Making me believe that its a caching issue. I can't figure out why else the Analyzer would still report synonyms after I delete them.
- Schema.xml has the solr.SynonymFilterFactory at the query type, with synonyms=synonyms.txt, expand=true

> 

Anyone have any advice?

**EDIT** This is my solr.xml

```
vi /etc/tomcat6/Catalina/localhost/solr.xml
-----
<Context docBase="/data/solr/solr.war" debug="0" privileged="true" allowLinking="true" crossContext="true">
  <Environment name="solr/home" type="java.lang.String" value="/data/solr" override="true" />
</Context>
-----
```

Comment: Did you restart solr or reload the core?

Comment: Hm haven't tried that yet, judging by this answer (http://serverfault.com/a/304820) I would assume I'm suppose to specify a cores configuration in solr.xml. I'll post my solr.xml, see my edit

Comment: Also, would restarting tomcat be effective?